# management tools exchange server 2003

Tags: windows-7, exchange-2003

Please, I’m looking for management tools exchange server 2003  in order to install it in windows 7.
Regards.

Comment: 32 bit or 64 bit?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately MS did not release the Exchange System Manager for Windows 7, however they did release a version for Vista that does work on Windows 7. To install this, do the following:

- Ensure that [RSAT for Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7d2f6ad7-656b-4313-a005-4e344e43997d) are installed
- Download the [Exchange System Manager for Windows Vista](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=3403d74e-8942-421b-8738-b3664559e46f&displaylang=en)
- Use WinRar or other tool to extract the contents of this download
- Run the ESMVISTA.MSI file with the q switch for the run prompt or command line -  `ESMVISTA.MSI /q` this will suppress the check for the Vista OS and allow it be installed.